# Access-Control-Allow-Origin issue, even though it should work

Tags: node.js, deployment

Keep in mind that it's my first time deploying whole package app (meaning frontend + backend) and maybe im missing something obvious.

I hosted both front and backend and now Im trying to login in my app in production.

However Im getting Access-Control-Allow-Origin error.

I setup my back end like this:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", 'http://myapp.net');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Content-Length, X-Requested-With');
    next();
});
```

and want to access http://myappAPI.net/login but getting this error:

> Failed to load http://myappAPI.net/login: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://myapp.net' is therefore not allowed access.
>   The response had HTTP status code 502. If an opaque response serves
>   your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource
>   with CORS disabled.

what am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
res.header(..)
```

try

```
res.setHeader(...)
```

[The attributes headers is read only](https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.0/api/http.html#request.headers)

Comment: What happen if you add a status like res.status(200) to your function? Is it stil’ giving a 502 ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I found (which is not the best one cause I don't know this package after all) is to install the package *cors* >
*npm install cors --save*

then in your code:

```
cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())
```

If you want to know much about cors : https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Comment: It apparently sets "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" to a * aka wildcard, which is not allowed allowing to the console error.

Comment: It is if you use it as I set it. But you could define the routes separatly.

Comment: When configured properly on a route I just go full circle, back to the errors presented in the main post